# Could not print out inside of the for loop

Tags: c++, loops, fstream

I have code that needs to print out the file and also find some value from the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string input;
  fstream nameFile;
  nameFile.open("data.txt", ios::in);

  if (nameFile) {
    getline(nameFile, input);
    while (nameFile) {
      cout << input << endl;
      getline(nameFile, input);
    }
  } else {
    cout << " ERROR : cannot open file.\n ";
  }

  int largest_1{};
  int largest_2{};
  int largest_3{};

  for (int a{}, b{}, c{}, d{}, e{}; nameFile >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;) {

    if (c > largest_1)
      largest_1 = c;
    if (d > largest_2)
      largest_2 = d;
    else if (e > largest_3)
      largest_3 = e;

    std::cout << "The largest value 1 is " << largest_1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "The largest value 2 is " << largest_2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "The largest value 3 is " << largest_3 << '\n';
  }
}
```

However, after I run this code, it didn't print inside of the for loop. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: The first loop reads to the end of the file. The second loop can't read anything so it is never entered.

Comment: How to make sure that the second loop will be read ?

Comment: We don't know. What is the purpose of the first loop? Do you need it?

Comment: do you mean the if loop ?

Comment: Add `namefile.seekg(0);` before the second loop to rewind the file. If you're not using C++11 or newer you may also need `namefile.clear();` to clear the error state before the seek. You could also close the file and open it again.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have tried it and it works. Thank you so much. Thank you thank you. You are literally my lifesaver now ^_^

Answer (score 0):

When you read through a file you are changing it's read pointer. After the first loop, the read pointer was moved all the way to EOF, so when you try to read again, it won't because it's at the end of the file. What you want to do before your 2nd loop is to go `namefile.seekg(0);`

This will reset the read pointer to the begining and allow you to read the file again.